# Data Structure for Equity (Share) Ownership

Tags: python

I am looking for the appropriate data structure to use to represent equity ownership of a corporation (i.e. the shareholders).

Each corporation must have unique attributes such as its own tax rate, and must be able to have shareholders. Those shareholders need to be either another corporation or an individual, each with their own unique attributes.

I want to be able to query a corporation to determine who all of its shareholders are, or query a shareholder and determine which companies it holds equity in.

I considered having a Shareholder class which holds a list of individual Ownership items, which in turn hold a Corporation class, as shown below. However, this would not allow me to determine for a given corporation who all the shareholders are.

```py
class Shareholder:
    # holds multiple ownership objects
    def __init__(self, name, tax_rate, equity_ownership=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.tax_rate = tax_rate
        self.equity_ownership = equity_ownership

class Ownership:
    def __init__(self, corporation, ownership_fraction, equity_basis):
        self.corporation = corporation
        self.ownership_fraction = ownership_fraction
        self.equity_basis = equity_basis

class SimpleCorp(Shareholder):
    def __init__(self, name, tax_rate=0, equity_ownership=[], corp_type="C"):
        Shareholder.__init__(self, name, tax_rate, equity_ownership)
        self.corp_type = corp_type
```

Any recommendation for how to structure this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Be careful with using lists as a default argument for your methods. It's a Python gotcha. More info at the beginning of this article: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Comment: Consider modeling the relationship itself as a class, like you can model a graph as a collection of edge instances which connect node instances.

Comment: Basically your data model consists of (1) a collection of corporations, (2) a collection of individuals, and (3) a collection of ownership relationships (corporation-to-corporation and individual-to-corporation). With that in mind, one approach could be to create an `Individual` object for each individual, a `Corporation` object for each corporation and a `Relation` object for each (one-to-one one-way) ownership relationship. Then create a `DataModel` object that holds all the Individuals, Corporations and Relations as attributes, and also provides all the desired query methods.